# For what this code show me an error?

Tags: jquery

I create this code in my html file:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><span id="x1">6</span></td>
        <td>
            <select id="y1">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><span id="z1">X</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span id="x2">6</span></td>
        <td>
            <select id="y2">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><span id="z2">X</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="total">TOTAL</div>
```

And I create this code in my .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").change(function () {
        var m = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
            var x = "#x" + i;
            var y = "#y" + i;
            var z = "#z" + i;
            var first = $(x).text();
            var seconde = $(y).val();
            var third = first * seconde;
            $(z).html(third);
            var m = m + third;
        }
        $("#total").text(m);
    });
});
```

When I run html file and run the code, in #total ID show me `NaN`. But other sections work well. Whats wrong in this code?

Comment: What you want to count?  It is hard to see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Its very simply code for shopping cart . Its my basket and just example .

Comment: made a fiddle with your code and seems to be working fine https://jsfiddle.net/bmyfpgms/

Comment: @user7549259 In order for this questions to be appropriate on StackOverflow, you should provide more details to help other reproduce this issue, for example, the browser type and version, exact error details, message, etc.  Also, you should make the title of the question more descriptive then "why is this error happening?"

Comment: Your code works for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4g8ozqe2/. What errors in the console are you getting?

Comment: use `first = parseInt($(x).text())` and `seconde = parseInt($(y).val())` to cast your variable as integer